# Wait until swift for loop network requests finishes executing(Native without using any framework)

Tags: ios, swift, api, grand-central-dispatch

So i have a request task and inside of it i have a loop with another request task. I want to complete the loop request task and then continue to complete the other one.

```
let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   tableView.reloadData()
   fetchData()

   dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
       self.tableView.reloadData()
   }
}

func fetchData() {
        var movies: String?
        dispatchGroup.enter()
        print("Enter fetchData")
        let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
                if error != nil || data == nil {
                    print("Client error!")
                    return
                }
                guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, (200...299).contains(response.statusCode) else {
                    print("Server error!")
                    return
                }
                guard let mime = response.mimeType, mime == "application/json" else {
                    print("Wrong MIME type!")
                    return
                }
                do {

                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String : Any]
                    if let result = json?["results"] as? Array<Dictionary<String, Any>> {
                        for results in result {
                            self.char = StarWarsData.init(name: results["name"] as! String, height: results["height"] as! String, mass: results["mass"] as! String, gender: results["gender"] as! String, birthyear: results["birth_year"] as! String, film: results["films"] as! [String])
                            let name = self.char.name
                            let height = self.char.height
                            let mass = self.char.mass
                            let gender = self.char.gender
                            let birthyear = self.char.birthyear
                            let charFilms = self.char.film
                            for theFilms in charFilms {
                                self.fetchFilms(films: theFilms) { (filmNames) in
                                    movies = filmNames
                                    print(movies!)
                                }

                            }
                            let item = StarWarsData(name: name, height: height, mass: mass, gender: gender, birthyear: birthyear, film: charFilms)
                            self.dataArray.append(item)
                            self.dataNames.append(name)
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                self.tableView.reloadData()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }catch {
                    print("JSON error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            print("Leaving fetchData")
            self.dispatchGroup.leave()
        }
        task.resume()
    }

func fetchFilms(films: String, taskCallBack: @escaping (String) -> ()) {
        let url = URL(string: films)!
        var filmsArr: [String] = []
        var item: String!
        var joinItem: String!
        dispatchGroup.enter()
        print("Enter fetchFilms")
        let task = self.session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

                if error != nil || data == nil {
                    print("Client error!")
                    return
                }
                guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, (200...299).contains(response.statusCode) else {
                    print("Server error!")
                    return
                }
                guard let mime = response.mimeType, mime == "application/json" else {
                    print("Wrong MIME type!")
                    return
                }
                do {
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String : Any]
                    if let results = json?["title"] as? String {
                        for results in results {
                            item = String(results)
                            filmsArr.append(item)
                        }
                        joinItem = filmsArr.joined(separator: "")
                        taskCallBack(joinItem)
                    }
                }catch {
                    print("JSON error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            print("Leaving fetchFilms")
            self.dispatchGroup.leave()
            })
             task.resume()
    }
```

So check the print statements and you will understand what i want.
This is my output.

```
Enter fetchData
Enter fetchFilms
Enter fetchFilms
Enter fetchFilms
Enter fetchFilms
Enter fetchFilms
Enter fetchFilms
Enter fetchFilms
Enter fetchFilms
Enter fetchFilms
Enter fetchFilms
Leaving fetchData
A New Hope
Leaving fetchFilms
The Empire Strikes Back
Leaving fetchFilms
Return of the Jedi
Leaving fetchFilms
The Force Awakens
Leaving fetchFilms
Revenge of the Sith
Leaving fetchFilms
The Empire Strikes Back
Leaving fetchFilms
The Phantom Menace
Leaving fetchFilms
Attack of the Clones
Leaving fetchFilms
Revenge of the Sith
Leaving fetchFilms
The Phantom Menace
Leaving fetchFilms
Notify table reloaded
```

Simply i want this:

```
Enter fetchData
Enter fetchFilms
Enter fetchFilms
Enter fetchFilms
Enter fetchFilms
Enter fetchFilms
Enter fetchFilms
Enter fetchFilms
Enter fetchFilms
Enter fetchFilms
Enter fetchFilms
A New Hope
Leaving fetchFilms
The Empire Strikes Back
Leaving fetchFilms
Return of the Jedi
Leaving fetchFilms
The Force Awakens
Leaving fetchFilms
Revenge of the Sith
Leaving fetchFilms
The Empire Strikes Back
Leaving fetchFilms
The Phantom Menace
Leaving fetchFilms
Attack of the Clones
Leaving fetchFilms
Revenge of the Sith
Leaving fetchFilms
The Phantom Menace
Leaving fetchFilms
Leaving fetchData
Notify table reloaded
```

I want somehow to pause the task before the print statement `Leaving fetchData` and complete the whole process of `func fetchFilms` and then continue with the print statement `Leaving fetchData`. Actually `func fetchData()` complete before the `func fetchFilms` ends and i don't take the films that i want.BTW the `print(movies!)` statement giving me the films but it's too late.

Comment: You are using DispatchGroup wrong. You are declaring it in the wrong place and you need _two_ of them, not some shared thing.

Comment: Ok can you give an example on how specifically have and where to call them?

Comment: Do a search. DispatchGroup has been explained here very well many times.

Answer (score 0):

[Edit]: To highlight the medium post main idea, also removed semaphores, not really a swift style.

You may use Operation in case you want a function to be finished before another function call(especially in case of datatasks).

I found a better post to navigate you through how to implement it.
https://medium.com/@oleary.audio/simultaneous-asynchronous-calls-in-swift-9c1f5fd3ea32

Comment: I have tried with semaphores without luck. Maybe i was implemented it wrong but i'll check that medium post. Thank you

Comment: The medium post contains how you can use shared datatask and operations to wait until multiply api calls have response, then update the interface. Hope it helps